# Django Authentication using external web services

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to use Django Authentication but with external web service calls. By calling a web service with a username and password payload. 
 Is there any tutorial or possibility to do that? I am trying with the Remote User but it is not working. I am able to reach the point that authenticate call is working but still stuck with the login page

```
class AppRemoteUserBackend (RemoteUserBackend):

create_unknown_user = True

def authenticate (self, **credentials):
    //getting the user info by webservie call 
    customer = CustomerManagementService.getSelf(credentials)
    myUser= MyUser ()
    myUser.info= customer
    myUser.id = customer['id']
    myUser.username = credentials['username']
    t = myUser.is_authenticated()

    return myUser


from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser (User):



objects = None 

username = ""  
info= ""

def get_group_permissions (self):

    return [] 

def get_and_delete_messages (self):

    return []
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a REST API framework, you can handle a basic HTTP authentication that way:

**Backend code**

```
import base64
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text, DjangoUnicodeDecodeError
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def basic_auth(http_request):

    if 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' in http_request.META:
        authdata = http_request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split()
        if len(authdata) == 2 and authdata[0].lower() == "basic":
            try:
                raw = authdata[1].encode('ascii')
                auth_parts = base64.b64decode(raw).split(b':')
            except:
                return
            try:
                uname, passwd = (smart_text(auth_parts[0]),
                                 smart_text(auth_parts[1]))
            except DjangoUnicodeDecodeError:
                return

            user = authenticate(username=uname, password=passwd)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                # We don't user auth.login(http_request, user) because
                # may be running without session
                http_request.user = user
                return True
    return
```

**Client code**

I personnaly use Requests because it's easy to pass credentials in the payload that way:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth("some-username", "some-password")

res = requests.get("http://my-url", auth=auth)
```

Comment: This isn't using an external authentication service, right? How can we use a service intended for single sign on?